# How can I access the result I get from my GET request inside res.on function?

Tags: node.js

I'd want to use the d variable outside the res.on function but it doesn't see it.

In other words, how can I access the result I get from my GET request. (I want to send it to the client side)

Currently I can just  log it with the process.stdout.write(d) line. Anywhere outside res.on it doesn't work (even if I declare it outside). Thank you.

```
let data;

app.post("/api/route", function(req, res) {


var options = {
    host : 'api.track-pod.com',
    port : 443,
    path : '/Route/Code/R000409',
    method : 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-API-KEY': 'xxx'//req.body.value.key
      }
};

req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
  
    res.on('data', d => {
      //process.stdout.write(d)
      data =+d;
    })
  })
  
  req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
  
  res.on("end", d => {
    // Now all the data is stored in the data variable
    processData(data);
  });
  function processData(data) {
    return data;
  }
  res.send({"data":processData(data)})
  

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use promises to do that:

```
const https = require('https')
const options = {
  hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET'
};

const req = () => {
  return new Promise((response, reject) => {
  let result = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log('in here');
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

            let data;
            res.on('data', d => {
                data += d;
                // process.stdout.write(d)
             })
  
  
             res.on('error', error => {
              console.error(error);
              reject(error);
            })
  
            res.on("end", d => {
              response(data);
            });
   })
   result.end();
  })
}


req().then(data => { console.log(data)}).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: not sure if it is possible. I've tried that and it prints "req is not defined" for the last line
`let data;
   return new Promise((res, req) => {
          res.on('data', d => {
              data += d;
              process.stdout.write(d)
           })


          req.on('error', error => {
            console.error(error);
            rej(error);
          })

          res.on("end", d => {
          res(data);
          });
 })
})
req.then(data => { console.log(data)}).catch(console.log);`

Comment: I have updated the code, the reason was I was not ending the request sent using `https` module. Check the above code, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "end" event. Declare a data variable outside of the request body and process the data when all the data is downloaded.

```js
let data;

function processData(data) {
  // process the data here
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
 
  res.on('data', d => {
    data += d;
  })

  res.on("end", d => {
    // Now all the data is stored in the data variable
    processData(data);
  });
})
```

Another way would be piping the res into a writable stream because the res is a readable stream.

```
res.pipe(any_writable_stream_here);
```

Comment: dear @h-sifat, I've tried multiple times your advice. however, it still doesn't work. I want to send data to the server. I've updated the code in the question with my recent attempt. Would you be so kind to tell me what's wrong?